# Coloring/manipulating parts of a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

What options do I have to draw on a textarea?

I know some wysiwyg editors that do it. I'm not sure what's the approach they use, and will have a look at them to understand, but I know that things like [tinymce](http://www.tinymce.com/) have been around for a while, so I'm guessing there may be more modern approaches these days.

More specifically, what I need is to set the color, or the background color, of a part of text, and sometimes to add some icons.

Here's a mockup of what I'm envisioning:
[image: example]

Comment: tinyMCE uses contentEditable; a html boolean property (`<div contenteditable />`) look it up. Doing any styling in a textarea is not possible though.

Comment: Didn't knew about contenteditable, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like other form controls, the styling you can apply to a textarea is quite limited. For an example of some styles you can apply, [check out this page](http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/styling-form-controls-revisited/text-input-multiple/).

Most WYSIWYG (rich text) editors (e.g. tinyMCE and CKEditor) are using [contentEditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Content_Editable) on a div or iframe and not a textarea even though it may look like a textarea.

Comment: Not even on a div, they use an iframe with contentEditable which enables manipulation of the whole document in the iframe; though it works just the same, the iframe is used for wider browser support.